# pandas, selecting rows with list/series of index

Tags: pandas

It seems simple, yet hard to get it right.

For a given list (of index), I'd like to get column values from a dataframe.

Below, for given `item_ids`, find the list of means (in the same order as item_ids) from dataframe `self.item_mean`

```
(Pdb) item_ids.head()
0    1661
1    2791
2      77
3    3076
4    2862
Name: review_meta_id, dtype: object

(Pdb) df_item_mean.head()
   review_meta_id      mean
0               1  4.236750
1              10  3.898477
2             100  3.462879
3            1001  3.410140
4            1002  4.164352

(Pdb) item_means = df_item_mean.set_index('review_meta_id').loc[item_ids]
*** KeyError: "None of [Index(['1661', '2791', '77', '3076', '2862', '1469', '2794', '3379', '3430',\n       '3157', '3077', '2224', '3172', '964', '2808', '2885', '1656', '2850'],\n      dtype='object', name='review_meta_id')] are in the [index]"


(Pdb) type(item_ids)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: The name of dataframe may cause some problem `self.item_mean`

Comment: @Wen-Ben I changed the var name if it is confusing, I don't think naming could cause problem, are you saying it might?

Comment: would you like print `type(item_ids)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben did print it

Comment: so I found out the reason. item_ids are of integer type, and df_item_mean['review_meta_id'] are object type...

Comment: did you try df_item_mean.set_index('review_meta_id').loc[item_ids.values]